# Heroku Local Not Working?

Tags: python, heroku, terminal

I'm trying to deploy my python app locally using `heroku local`, but I keep receiving the following output:

```
(env) iMac:myproject Me$  heroku local
[WARN] No ENV file found
[OKAY] Trimming display Output to 61 Columns
12:15:08 AM web.1 |  [2016-04-05 00:15:08 -0700] [47311] [INFO] Starting gunicorn …
12:15:08 AM web.1 |  [2016-04-05 00:15:08 -0700] [47311] [ERROR] Connection in use…
12:15:08 AM web.1 |  [2016-04-05 00:15:08 -0700] [47311] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 sec…
12:15:09 AM web.1 |  [2016-04-05 00:15:09 -0700] [47311] [ERROR] Connection in use…
12:15:09 AM web.1 |  [2016-04-05 00:15:09 -0700] [47311] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 sec…
12:15:10 AM web.1 |  [2016-04-05 00:15:10 -0700] [47311] [ERROR] Connection in use…
12:15:10 AM web.1 |  [2016-04-05 00:15:10 -0700] [47311] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 sec…
12:15:11 AM web.1 |  [2016-04-05 00:15:11 -0700] [47311] [ERROR] Connection in use…
12:15:11 AM web.1 |  [2016-04-05 00:15:11 -0700] [47311] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 sec…
12:15:12 AM web.1 |  [2016-04-05 00:15:12 -0700] [47311] [ERROR] Connection in use…
12:15:12 AM web.1 |  [2016-04-05 00:15:12 -0700] [47311] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 sec…
12:15:13 AM web.1 |  [2016-04-05 00:15:13 -0700] [47311] [ERROR] Can't connect to …
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  null
12:15:13 AM web.1 Exited Abnormally
(env) iMac:myproject Me$
```

The env folder is in the app.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is not the environment FILE that is the problem.

As you can see from: 
`[WARN] No ENV file found`

It is as warning.

I am not sure what is wrong here. Does the logs say anything?

Try this though (I have to run my local server like this every time):

```
heroku local web -f Procfile
```

Answer (score 1):

env is the file with the name:`.env` (not the folder). Find more information at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#add-a-config-var-to-your-env-file